# JAXB Help needed for mapping Custom Objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have XML receiving from some server. I need to unmarshall that xml to java objects and marshall java objects to xml.

How Can i do that?.

Below is my XML format.

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <order>
            <row no="1">
                <AB val="ID">205</AB>
                <AB val="NAME">JS</AB>
                <AB val="DETAILS">
                    <prod no="1">
                        <AB val="PRODID">205</AB>
                        <AB val="NAME">Prod1</AB>
                    </prod>
                    <prod no="2">
                        <AB val="PRODID">206</AB>
                        <AB val="NAME">Prod2</AB>
                    </prod>
                </AB>
            </row>
        </order>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Comment: Do you have an xsd for the format?

Comment: Sorry XSD not available

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jaxb2-maven-plugin` with `xjc` goal to generate your java classes from xml schema (xsd) during build (you can generate xml schema from xml by any online generator, for example use [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)).

You can also just use `xjc` from console and generate your classes beforehand, it's built in into java (see `<your jdk path>/bin/xjc.exe`).

Then simply use marshaller/unmarshaller, to do the work, for example:

```java
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourClazz.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
YourClazz yourclazz = (YourClazz) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshall(new File("path/to/your/xml"));
```

btw I suggest caching `JAXBContext` instances, use `Map<Class<?>, JAXBContext>`. Do not cache marshaller/unmarshaller tho.

Comment: It is generating  
    protected List<Serializable> content;
Here i need type of that element like string, int